# Starting PHP session from email link

Tags: php, session, post, cookies, get

I have an email containing links to various products that I have sent to potential clients.  When clicking on the link, I want to take the user to a page with a form on it.  Based on what product link they clicked, I want the value of a hidden input field to equal the product name.

I also want the page to only be accessible via the link in the email.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: There's no way your server can determine whether or not the link was actually clicked from within an email. Anyone could type the link out and access the same page.

Answer (score 2):

The link in the email can be something like

```
http://example.com/my-script.php?email=<email_address>&token=<token>
```

where the `<token>` value is computed by your script (in a secret way) based on the email address; Then on my-script.php check if the received token value is valid (by computing the token again from the email address and comparing the two).

Of course, anyone with this link can just go to the page, but they wouldn't be able to change the value of the email address. To prevent that, you would have to have user accounts, and the user would need to log in

Comment: email could be email hash making it more secure.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is quite simple. You just use the parameter from the URL ($_GET['pruduct_name']) and put it into the value field of your hidden input like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['product_name']; ?>" />
```

It will be quite difficult to make a URL only accessible via the email link.

Answer (score 1):

When you send the email, you could generate a random alphanumeric sequence, that you add to the querystring of the URL `yourdomain.com/page.php?id=sdlasjh234897dhaksjhda` and save to your database, along with which product it is connected to.

When the user arrive at the page, you check your database for that id. If it isn't in your db, then show a message that the link is invalid. Otherwise show the form and populate the hidden input with the product name you save along with your id in your db.